# How to check if an event is being handled in F#

Tags: f#

What is the F# equivalent of the following C# code? Specifically, I need to check if an event is being handled.

```
protected virtual void OnClicked(ClickEventArgs e) {
    if (this.Clicked != null) //how can I perform this check in F#
        this.Clicked(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Not sure where the best place is to post F# feature requests, but I posted a request on hubfs.net to expose the multicast delegate member in Event (and related types). It would make this check so much easier.

Comment: Here's the feature request: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/ShowThread.aspx?PostID=12910#12910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured this thing out. Taking a cue from [Don Syme's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20081121174012/http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/articles/FSharpCompositionalEvents.aspx), specifically the section "The Implementation of the IEvent Module."

Instead of the following:

```
let validationFailedEvent = new Event<DataValidationEventHandler, DataValidationEventArgs>()
```

I had to implement IEvent myself and create a variable to hold the invocation list:

```
let mutable listeners: Delegate = null
    
let validationFailedEvent = { new IEvent<DataValidationEventHandler, DataValidationEventArgs> with 
                                    member x.AddHandler(d) = 
                                        listeners <- Delegate.Combine(listeners, d)
                                    member x.RemoveHandler(d) =
                                        listeners <- Delegate.Remove(listeners, d)
                                    member x.Subscribe(observer) =
                                        let h = new Handler<_>(fun sender args -> observer.OnNext(args))
                                        (x :?> IEvent<_,_>).AddHandler(h)
                                        { new System.IDisposable with 
                                             member x.Dispose() = (x :?> IEvent<_,_>).RemoveHandler(h) } }
```

Then, to check if there are listeners, and, if not, raise an exception:

```
member private x.fireValidationFailedEvent(e:DataValidationEventArgs) =
    match listeners with
    | null -> failwith "No listeners"
    | d -> d.DynamicInvoke([| box x; box e |])
```

Comment: Also makes clearly visible the C# compiler does sugar many things away.

Comment: With respect to the sexiness of C#, you can of course encapsulate this logic in your own `RequiresSubscriptionEvent<'a>` class and make it as easy to use as a normal F# event: `let ev = RequiresSubscriptionEvent<_>`, `[<CLIEvent>]member x.ValidationFailed = ev.Publish`, etc.

Personally, I find the lack of null checking in normal F# event code to be pretty sexy.

Comment: +1 Good idea. I agree with you about null checking, but the null check is merely how to find out if an event is handled in C#. It could be done differently in F#. Perhaps the listeners could be stored in a list (could check if it's empty) or an Option (check for None).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to implement `RequiresSubscriptionEvent` is to build on top of the existing `Event` functionality (using composition) and just add a counter that counts the number of registered handlers and add a property `HasListeners` (or even publish the number of listeners if you wanted...)

This makes the code a bit easier to use and hopefuly also safer, because if you don't check whether it has any listneres, it will still work as the usual F# code. And if you want to perform the check, you can...

```
type RequiresSubscriptionEvent<_>() = 
  let evt = new Event<_>()
  let mutable counter = 0
  let published = 
    { new IEvent<_> with
      member x.AddHandler(h) = 
        evt.Publish.AddHandler(h)
        counter <- counter + 1; 
      member x.RemoveHandler(h) = 
        evt.Publish.RemoveHandler(h)
        counter <- counter - 1; 
      member x.Subscribe(s) = 
        let h = new Handler<_>(fun _ -> s.OnNext)
        x.AddHandler(h)
        { new System.IDisposable with 
            member y.Dispose() = x.RemoveHandler(h) } }
  member x.Trigger(v) = evt.Trigger(v)
  member x.Publish = published
  member x.HasListeners = counter > 0
```

Sample usage:

```
type Demo() =
  let evt = new RequiresSubscriptionEvent<_>()
  [<CLIEvent>]
  member x.OnSomething = evt.Publish
  member x.FooThatFiresSomething() = 
    if evt.HasListeners then
      evt.Trigger("foo!")
    else
      printfn "No handlers!"
```

Even though this isn't a part of standard F# libraries, it shows the great advantage of F# *first class* events. If there is some missing functionality, you can simply implement it yourself!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that this will handle repeated additions/removals of the same physical delegate correctly, if that is needed.

Comment: I also don't think this will keep an accurate count of listeners because you don't know if the calls to Add/RemoveHandler changed the invocation list.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I was hoping that AddHandler/RemoveHandler would throw an exception in those weird cases. It works well if you add one handler multiple times, but unfortunately, you'll never know whether removing handler did something (you can remove handler that wasn't added and it doesn't complain)...

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you don't need to do that check in F# (the event infrastructure checks for you):

```
type T() =
  let ev = new Event<_>()
  [<CLIEvent>]
  member x.Event = ev.Publish
  member x.OnClicked() =
    ev.Trigger()
```

Comment: I want to throw an exception if the event is not being handled (similar to the way XmlReader throws an exception if XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler is not set). This code will be called from C#.

Answer (score 1):

I followed kvb's suggestion and put this logic in a class. I copied Event from the F# sources and added a Handled property, which checks if the Delegate is null. I tried adding to, then removing handlers from the event to make sure it gets set back to null, and indeed it does.

```
    type EventEx<'Delegate,'Args when 'Delegate : delegate<'Args,unit> and 'Delegate :> System.Delegate >() = 
        let mutable multicast : System.Delegate = null
        static let argTypes = 
            let instanceBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
            let mi = typeof<'Delegate>.GetMethod("Invoke",instanceBindingFlags)
            mi.GetParameters() |> (fun arr -> arr.[1..]) |> Array.map (fun p -> p.ParameterType)

        member x.Handled = (multicast <> null)

        member x.Trigger(sender:obj,args:'Args) = 
            match multicast with 
            | null -> ()
            | d -> 
                if argTypes.Length = 1 then 
                    d.DynamicInvoke([| sender; box args |]) |> ignore
                else
                    d.DynamicInvoke(Array.append [| sender |] (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(box args))) |> ignore
        member x.Publish = 
            { new IEvent<'Delegate,'Args> with 
                member x.AddHandler(d) =
                    multicast <- System.Delegate.Combine(multicast, d)
                member x.RemoveHandler(d) = 
                    multicast <- System.Delegate.Remove(multicast, d) 
                member e.Subscribe(observer) = 
                   let h = new Handler<_>(fun sender args -> observer.OnNext(args))
                   (e :?> IEvent<_,_>).AddHandler(h)
                   { new System.IDisposable with 
                        member x.Dispose() = (e :?> IEvent<_,_>).RemoveHandler(h) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This article here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109030949/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/05/22/122302.aspx) says you do not need to check for null events in F#, though I don't know what his reference is.

This article [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20081121174012/http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/articles/FSharpCompositionalEvents.aspx) by Don Symes goes into F# events in quite a bit of detail. It looks like events are not owned by the class in F#

From the above,

> it is that events are now first-class
> values in the F# langauge.  Indeed,
> events are not a separate notion at
> all in the language design, rather,
> events are just values of type
> Microsoft.FSharp.Idioms.IEvent<_>, and
> .NET events are effectively just
> properties of this type.

And

> One of the restrictions of C# is that
> events can only exist as members
> within classes.  With the F# model,
> new event values can be created just
> as values as part of any expression.

Comment: That's true, you don't need to check if handlers are attached to fire the event. I need to check for other reasons. (See my comment in kvb's post.)

Comment: hehe... I was searching google for "F sharp listeners" and it came up with results about the musical note F# and a listening audience.

Comment: So if we figure this out we can let musicians know how to check if anyone's listening.

Comment: No F# expert, but I was reading through this article http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1767.entry and it looks like he is iterating through a collection of observers. Maybe this can give you some ideas.